# BitVector64 implementation

Tags: c#, bitwise, bitset

I have implemented a structure to handle BitVector64 (default System library support only 32 bits).
In the implementation i have added some custom method to manipulate bits inside the vector.

I would like comments and suggestions about the implementation, because i am concerned about correctness and performance.

Ps : i had to omit an output string, because text inside create problem to the parser here (so the code is was not displayed well in the page).
Any way you can find the full code in this git repository :
https://github.com/ItSkary/BitVector64

```
public struct BitVector64 : ICloneable
{
    private readonly static UInt64[] _MASK = new UInt64[]
    {
        0x01,
        0x02,
        0x04,
        0x08,
        0x10,
        0x20,
        0x40,
        0x80,
        0x100,
        0x200,
        0x400,
        0x800,
        0x1000,
        0x2000,
        0x4000,
        0x8000,
        0x10000,
        0x20000,
        0x40000,
        0x80000,
        0x100000,
        0x200000,
        0x400000,
        0x800000,
        0x1000000,
        0x2000000,
        0x4000000,
        0x8000000,
        0x10000000,
        0x20000000,
        0x40000000,
        0x80000000,
        0x100000000,
        0x200000000,
        0x400000000,
        0x800000000,
        0x1000000000,
        0x2000000000,
        0x4000000000,
        0x8000000000,
        0x10000000000,
        0x20000000000,
        0x40000000000,
        0x80000000000,
        0x100000000000,
        0x200000000000,
        0x400000000000,
        0x800000000000,
        0x1000000000000,
        0x2000000000000,
        0x4000000000000,
        0x8000000000000,
        0x10000000000000,
        0x20000000000000,
        0x40000000000000,
        0x80000000000000,
        0x100000000000000,
        0x200000000000000,
        0x400000000000000,
        0x800000000000000,
        0x1000000000000000,
        0x2000000000000000,
        0x4000000000000000,
        0x8000000000000000,
    };

    private readonly static Byte[] _REVERSE = new Byte[]
    {
        0   ,
        128 ,
        64  ,
        192 ,
        32  ,
        160 ,
        96  ,
        224 ,
        16  ,
        144 ,
        80  ,
        208 ,
        48  ,
        176 ,
        112 ,
        240 ,
        8   ,
        136 ,
        72  ,
        200 ,
        40  ,
        168 ,
        104 ,
        232 ,
        24  ,
        152 ,
        88  ,
        216 ,
        56  ,
        184 ,
        120 ,
        248 ,
        4   ,
        132 ,
        68  ,
        196 ,
        36  ,
        164 ,
        100 ,
        228 ,
        20  ,
        148 ,
        84  ,
        212 ,
        52  ,
        180 ,
        116 ,
        244 ,
        12  ,
        140 ,
        76  ,
        204 ,
        44  ,
        172 ,
        108 ,
        236 ,
        28  ,
        156 ,
        92  ,
        220 ,
        60  ,
        188 ,
        124 ,
        252 ,
        2   ,
        130 ,
        66  ,
        194 ,
        34  ,
        162 ,
        98  ,
        226 ,
        18  ,
        146 ,
        82  ,
        210 ,
        50  ,
        178 ,
        114 ,
        242 ,
        10  ,
        138 ,
        74  ,
        202 ,
        42  ,
        170 ,
        106 ,
        234 ,
        26  ,
        154 ,
        90  ,
        218 ,
        58  ,
        186 ,
        122 ,
        250 ,
        6   ,
        134 ,
        70  ,
        198 ,
        38  ,
        166 ,
        102 ,
        230 ,
        22  ,
        150 ,
        86  ,
        214 ,
        54  ,
        182 ,
        118 ,
        246 ,
        14  ,
        142 ,
        78  ,
        206 ,
        46  ,
        174 ,
        110 ,
        238 ,
        30  ,
        158 ,
        94  ,
        222 ,
        62  ,
        190 ,
        126 ,
        254 ,
        1   ,
        129 ,
        65  ,
        193 ,
        33  ,
        161 ,
        97  ,
        225 ,
        17  ,
        145 ,
        81  ,
        209 ,
        49  ,
        177 ,
        113 ,
        241 ,
        9   ,
        137 ,
        73  ,
        201 ,
        41  ,
        169 ,
        105 ,
        233 ,
        25  ,
        153 ,
        89  ,
        217 ,
        57  ,
        185 ,
        121 ,
        249 ,
        5   ,
        133 ,
        69  ,
        197 ,
        37  ,
        165 ,
        101 ,
        229 ,
        21  ,
        149 ,
        85  ,
        213 ,
        53  ,
        181 ,
        117 ,
        245 ,
        13  ,
        141 ,
        77  ,
        205 ,
        45  ,
        173 ,
        109 ,
        237 ,
        29  ,
        157 ,
        93  ,
        221 ,
        61  ,
        189 ,
        125 ,
        253 ,
        3   ,
        131 ,
        67  ,
        195 ,
        35  ,
        163 ,
        99  ,
        227 ,
        19  ,
        147 ,
        83  ,
        211 ,
        51  ,
        179 ,
        115 ,
        243 ,
        11  ,
        139 ,
        75  ,
        203 ,
        43  ,
        171 ,
        107 ,
        235 ,
        27  ,
        155 ,
        91  ,
        219 ,
        59  ,
        187 ,
        123 ,
        251 ,
        7   ,
        135 ,
        71  ,
        199 ,
        39  ,
        167 ,
        103 ,
        231 ,
        23  ,
        151 ,
        87  ,
        215 ,
        55  ,
        183 ,
        119 ,
        247 ,
        15  ,
        143 ,
        79  ,
        207 ,
        47  ,
        175 ,
        111 ,
        239 ,
        31  ,
        159 ,
        95  ,
        223 ,
        63  ,
        191 ,
        127 ,
        255 ,
    };

    private UInt64 _data;

    /// <devdoc>
    /// <para>Initializes a new instance of the BitVector64 structure with the specified internal data.</para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public BitVector64(UInt64 data = 0)
    {
        _data = (UInt64)data;
    }

    /// <devdoc>
    /// <para>Initializes a new instance of the BitVector64 structure with the information in the specified 
    ///    value.</para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public BitVector64(BitVector64 value)
    {
        _data = value.Data;
    }

    /// <devdoc>
    /// <para>Initializes a new instance of the BitVector64 structure with the information in the specified 
    ///    value.
    ///  Note : not particulary efficient
    /// </para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public BitVector64(bool[] value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        if (value.Length <= 0 || value.Length > 64)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("The array provided sould be bound to the lenght between [1,64].");

        _data = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            if (value[i])
                this.Set(i);
        }
    }

    /// <devdoc>
    ///    returns the raw data stored in this bit vector...
    /// </devdoc>
    public UInt64 Data
    {
        get
        {
            return (UInt64)_data;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if (!(o is BitVector64))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return _data == ((BitVector64)o).Data;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the current status of a flag in the BitVector
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">>ndex of the bit to get</param>
    /// <returns>State of selected bit</returns>
    public bool Get(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 63)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Index should be bount to [0-63] values, actual Index :{index}");

        return (_data & _MASK[index]) != 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mark as On a bit in the vector
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Index of the bit to mark (left to right from 0 to 63)</param>
    public BitVector64 Set(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 63)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Index should be bount to [0-63] values, actual Index :{index}");

        _data |= _MASK[index];

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mark as Off a bit in the vector
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Index of the bit to mark (left to right from 0 to 63)</param>
    public BitVector64 Unset(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 63)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Index should be bount to [0-63] values, actual Index :{index}");

        _data &= ~_MASK[index];

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change the bit status
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Index of bit to change</param>
    /// <param name="status">The new bit status (true = 1, false = 0)</param>
    public BitVector64 Apply(int index, bool status)
    {
        return status ? this.Set(index) : this.Unset(index);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
        UInt64 locdata = _data;

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            if ((locdata & 0x01) != 0)
            {
                sb.Append("1");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("0");
            }
            locdata >>= 1;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Debug only, print a formatted bitString
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string StringFormatted()
    {
        char[] bits = this.ToString().ToCharArray();
        List<char> temp = bits.ToList();
        temp.Reverse();
        bits = temp.ToArray();

        string[] trunk = new string[8];
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
            trunk[7-i] = string.Join(" ", bits.Skip(i * 8).Take(8));
        string result = $@"!!Omitted!!";
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply the bits starting form certain bit of the bitvector, till a certain length of the supplied bits.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bits">UInt64 that retain the interesting bits</param>
    /// <param name="bitVectorApplyPoint">Starting point in the current bitvector [0,63]</param>
    /// <param name="bitsLength">Define how many of the supplied bits have to be taken into account [1,64].If there is not enought space after the apply point, bits are discarded.</param>
    public BitVector64 InsertBits (UInt64 bits, int bitVectorApplyPoint, int bitsLength)
    {
        if (bitVectorApplyPoint < 0 || bitVectorApplyPoint > 63)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"BitVectorApplyPoint should be bount to [0,63] values, actual Value :{bitVectorApplyPoint}");

        if (bitsLength < 1 || bitsLength > 64)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"BitsLength should be bount to [1,64] values, actual Value :{bitsLength}");

        UInt64 temporary = 0;
        int firstStageBlankShift  = 0;
        int secondStageBlankShift = 64 - bitsLength;
        int thirdStageBlankShift = 0;

        //first stage of original data, if any
        if (bitVectorApplyPoint > 0)
        {
            firstStageBlankShift = 64 - bitVectorApplyPoint;
            temporary = (_data << firstStageBlankShift) >> firstStageBlankShift;
        }

        //second stage of inserted data (mandatory)
        {
            secondStageBlankShift = 64 - bitsLength;
            temporary |= ((bits << secondStageBlankShift) >> secondStageBlankShift) << bitVectorApplyPoint;
        }

        //third stage of original data, if any
        thirdStageBlankShift = bitVectorApplyPoint + secondStageBlankShift;
        if (thirdStageBlankShift < 64)
        {
            temporary |= (_data >> thirdStageBlankShift) << thirdStageBlankShift;
        }

        _data = temporary;
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reverse the bits of the current BitVector64
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Return the current BitVector64</returns>
    public BitVector64 Reverse()
    {
        UInt64 b0 = _data & 0xFF;
        UInt64 b1 = _data & 0xFF00;
        UInt64 b2 = _data & 0xFF0000;
        UInt64 b3 = _data & 0xFF000000;
        UInt64 b4 = _data & 0xFF00000000;
        UInt64 b5 = _data & 0xFF0000000000;
        UInt64 b6 = _data & 0xFF000000000000;
        UInt64 b7 = _data & 0xFF00000000000000;

        b0 = _REVERSE[b0];
        b1 = _REVERSE[b1>>8 ];
        b2 = _REVERSE[b2>>16];
        b3 = _REVERSE[b3>>24];
        b4 = _REVERSE[b4>>32];
        b5 = _REVERSE[b5>>40];
        b6 = _REVERSE[b6>>48];
        b7 = _REVERSE[b7>>56];

        _data = 0;
        _data |= (b0 << 56) | (b1 << 48) | (b2 << 40) | (b3 << 32) | (b4 << 24) | (b5 << 16) | (b6 << 8) | b7 ;
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate the current array by a given numer of bits.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bits">Numbe of bits that need to be rotate [-256,256]</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public BitVector64 Rotate(int bits)
    {
        if (bits < -256 || bits > 256)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Bits should be bount to [-256,256] values, actual Value :{bits}");

        _data = (_data << bits) | (_data >> (64 - bits));

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shift the current array by a given numer of bits.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bits">Numbe of bits that need to be rotate [-64,64]</param>
    public BitVector64 Shift(int bits)
    {
        if (bits < -63 || bits > 63)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Bits should be bount to [-63,63] values, actual Value :{bits}");

        _data = (bits > 0) ? (_data << bits) : (_data >> -bits);

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Join the data of two vector
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector">Vector to join with current vector</param>
    /// <returns>The current vector update</returns>
    public BitVector64 Union(BitVector64 vector)
    {
        _data |= vector.Data;
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Intersect the data of two vector
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector">Vector to intersect with current vector</param>
    /// <returns>The current vector update</returns>
    public BitVector64 Intersect(BitVector64 vector)
    {
        _data &= vector.Data;
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Flip all bits in the current BitVector64
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Return the updated BitVector64</returns>
    public BitVector64 Negate()
    {
        _data = ~_data;
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Join the data of two vector, excluding the intersection 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector">Vector to exclusevelly unite with current vector</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public BitVector64 ExclusiveUnion(BitVector64 vector)
    {
        _data ^= vector.Data;
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the bit that are in current BitVector64 but not in the given one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector">Provided BitVector64</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public BitVector64 Left(BitVector64 vector)
    {
        _data |= vector.Data;
        _data &= (~vector.Data);
        
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the bit that are in the given BitVector64 but not in the current one
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector">Provided BitVector64</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public BitVector64 Right (BitVector64 vector)
    {
        UInt64 original = _data;

        _data |= vector.Data;
        _data &= (~original);

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a new BitVector64 built arround the given subset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="subsetStart">Start of selection [0,63]</param>
    /// <param name="subsetEnd">End of selection [0,63]</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public BitVector64 SubsetAtoB(ushort subsetStart, ushort subsetEnd)
    {
        if (subsetStart < 0 || subsetStart > 63 || subsetEnd < 0 || subsetEnd > 63)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Boundaries must be in the range [0,63] , actual : [{subsetStart},[{subsetEnd}]");

        UInt64 internalState = _data;
        internalState <<= 63-subsetEnd;
        internalState >>= subsetStart + (63 - subsetEnd);
        return new BitVector64(internalState);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a new BitVector64 built arround the given subset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="subsetStart">Start of selection [0,63]</param>
    /// <param name="subsetLength">Number of bits to select (could be negative if you would take bits before start)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public BitVector64 SubsetATillLength(ushort subsetStart, short subsetLength = 0)
    {
        if (subsetStart < 0 || subsetStart > 63)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"SubsetStart must be in the range [0,63] , actual : {subsetStart}");

        if (subsetLength == 0)
            subsetLength = (short)(63 - subsetStart);

        int firstBoundary = subsetStart;
        int secondBoundary = subsetStart + subsetLength + (subsetLength > 0 ? -1 : 1);

        if (firstBoundary > secondBoundary)
        {
            int tempBoundary = secondBoundary;
            secondBoundary = firstBoundary;
            firstBoundary = tempBoundary;
        }

        if (firstBoundary < 0 || firstBoundary > 63 || secondBoundary < 0 || secondBoundary > 63)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Boundaries must be in the range [0,63] , actual : [{firstBoundary},[{secondBoundary}]");

        return this.SubsetAtoB((ushort)firstBoundary, (ushort)secondBoundary);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate a deepcopy of current element
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Clone()
    {
        return new BitVector64(_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: `private readonly static ulong[] _MASK = Enumerable.Range(0, 63).Select(x => 1ul << x).ToArray()`.

Comment: @aepot right thx, nice trick to write a more compact code

Comment: Also you may use one of methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3587826/12888024) to instantiate the `_REVERSE` array.

Comment: One more tip: pattern matching with assignment and expression-like method body `public override bool Equals(object o) => o is BitVector64 vector ? _data == vector.Data : false`

Comment: `_data = (UInt64)data` redundant cast in `BitVector64` ctor and `Data` property. The property may be written simply as `public UInt64 Data => _data`. Check out [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) to ensure that you have a full compartibility with expression bodies.

Comment: An finally this one `public override string ToString() => Convert.ToString(_data, 2)`. There's a built-in `Convert` method.